# .NET C# - Importing Excel File - Sheet Name!

Tags: c#, .net, excel, npoi

I'm using the NPOI Library to import some data from an excel sheet to my database.

One early issue I'm curious about, is typically, to begin, you would have something like this:

**snippet**

```
 using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    HSSFWorkbook templateWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
                    HSSFSheet sheet = templateWorkbook.GetSheet("Sales");
```

My query is, what happens when the name of the worksheet is different each time, e.g. I plan to import sales data, and the sheets within the workbooks I receive from suppliers are titled by date.

Is there any way that you can specify GetSheet(); to just get the first sheet in the workbook?

Any pointers would be much appreciated,

thanks guys :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without trying it out I'd assume that you're looking for [getSheetAt](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#getSheetAt(int)).

So it would be:

```
HSSFSheet sheet = templateWorkbook.GetSheetAt(0);
```

Comment: I won't be trying for a few days but it seems like the logical answer. I'll mark it as correct once the time limit is up :) Thanks